# Add background image to window.rootViewController or window directly?

Tags: ios

I have a set of table views which the user can switch between using a tab bar controller, each table view has the same background. 
Rather than have each table display the same background image I instead can do either of these:

```
[myDelegate.window addSubview: theUIImageView];
```

or

```
[myDelegate.window.rootViewController addSubview:theUIImageView];
```

Both work, should one be used rather than the other and why?

I have a similar question for displaying an activity indicator.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the principle is that the window should have one root view controller at the top of the tree, so I would maintain that. Other rulesets are available!